# ACF - sync fields across all languages

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm currently working on a Wordpress site. There are multiple versions of the cite for different languages.
[image]

I created a custom field, `structure_data_link` that when I update in the english page is shown but it doesn't not sync with the other language pages. This means I would have to update that same field in every language manually. Is it possible to sync fields across all languages?
[image]
This means I have to update manually the field for every language.
[image]

How can I sync the field across all different language pages?

Comment: There should be an option when you edit your ACF field to: don't translate, copy, copy once or translate. In your case, you want copy - so it keeps the entered data synced across all languages. I can't remember if you need a WPML ACF addon plugin though.

Comment: @disinfor I added the option copy but when I update the fields, it doesn't seem to update in the other languages